# How can I pass context data to sylesheet 'src' and image 'src' attributes?

Tags: python, django, template-context

I have a `_layout.html` template as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% block linkcss %}{% endblock %}
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js' %}"></script>
        {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block head %}{% endblock %}
        <table class="page_content">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="content">
                        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page `home.html` extends the above with the following:

```
{% extends "generic/_layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ cust_title }}{% endblock %}
{% block linkcss %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '{{ cust_stylesheet }}' %}" />{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
<table class="head">
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <img src="{% static '{{ cust_header }}' %}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<table class="content">
        <thead align="center">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center">{{ cust_message }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

The view is generic in that the code checks the path and gets the context data and page ...here is an example:

```
# customer configurations constants:
CUSTOMER_CONFIGS = {
    'samplewebpage': {
        'context': {
            'cust_title': "Sample Customer Page",
            'cust_stylesheet': "SampleWeb/style.css",
            'cust_header': "SampleWeb/sample_header.png",
            'cust_message': "Welcome to Sample Web Page"
        },
        'home': "SampleWebPage/home.html"
    },
}

# generic view:
def index(request):
    path = request.path.replace("/", "")

    context = CUSTOMER_CONFIGS[path]['context']
    page = CUSTOMER_CONFIGS[path]['home']

    return render(request, page, context)
```

Directory structure:
[image: directory structure]

The `cust_title` works properly. So how can I pass the `cust_stylesheet` location and `cust_header` image source the same way?

The actual rendering resembles the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/%7B%7B%20cust_stylesheet%20%7D%7D" />  

<img src="/static/%7B%7B%20cust_header%20%7D%7D">
```

Comment: Try this: `<img src="{% static '{{ cust_header | safe }}' %}">`

Comment: I thought that was for `json` ...but you may have a point there.

Comment: @Gocht no, absolutely not. You can't call tags inside other tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right, that symbols are not needed. Sorry

Comment: @DanielRoseman: that seems limiting.

Comment: Using the name of the variable sould work I think: `{% static cust_header %}`

Comment: I'll give that a try @Gocht ... and I'll let you know.

Comment: @Gocht: this does work ...if you post as answer I'll accept. My answer is another option but likely less desired as the static resource is not dynamic (that is, doesn't rely on settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielRoseman says in comments *You can't call tags inside other tags.* But it is possible to use variables. Then you could try this:

```
{% static cust_header %}
```

That should print your string properly.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: the method provided by @Gocht is preferable as it takes advantage of the django settings.** I have left this answer simply as *another option* although maybe less favorable.

Based on @DanielRoseman's comment above - "You can't call tags inside other tags." - I changed the customer configurations and the dependent template as follows:

```
'samplewebpage': {
    'context': {
        'cust_title': "Sample Customer Page",
        'cust_stylesheet': "/static/SampleWeb/style.css",
        'cust_header': "/static/images/SampleWeb/sample_header.png",
        'cust_message': "Welcome to Sample Web Page"
    },
    'home': "SampleWebPage/home.html"
}

# template tags change  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ cust_stylesheet }}" />  

<img src="{{ cust_header }}">
```

Based on these changes, the page loads correctly with it's specific style.css and header image:

[image: sample web page with custom stylesheet and header image]